# How to set cookie independently for each subdomain, causing different cookies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, cookies

I am developing a rails application that supports various subdomains. There is a root domain such as example.com and a user logs in through it and then redirects a user to specific subdomain url, group.example.com and users can jump between subdomain urls depending on which group they have access to. How to I set up domain attribute in session cookie so that it would not be available between subdomains (ex2.example.com and ex3.example.com)?

EDIT:

I am sorry I meant session cookies. I want to send different cookies for each subdomain urls.

Comment: Can you provide your controller code here?

Comment: cookies stored in the browser are different for each subdomain by default. So going on each subdomain should require login again. Also see the [apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) gem for rails

Comment: ya, they are different, but he loggs in at / so by default it will be valid for all domains

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation of the [`Cookie`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) class. You can specify the domain when you create/delete the cookie.

```
cookies[:name] = {
  value: 'a yummy cookie',
  domain: 'ex2.example.com'
}
```

Of course, the value can be taken from the current request.

```
cookies[:name] = {
  value: 'a yummy cookie',
  domain: request.host
}
```

Here's the options

```
domain: nil  # Does not sets cookie domain. (default)
domain: :all # Allow the cookie for the top most level
             # domain and subdomains.
domain: %w(.example.com .example.org) # Allow the cookie
                                      # for concrete domain names.
```

Answer (score -1):

just add `domain: my.subdoma.in` to the cookie

btw: the user cookie should be available in all subdomains and you need to controller-check if he is having access to the group. this is the better way to do.